# UITabBar isTranslucent adds an additional UITabBar?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm experiencing something very strange. If the property of my `UITTabBar` `isTranslucent` is set to `false`, it adds this weird double like (or a view? I don't know what it is really) above of the `UITabBar`.

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
```

If this property is set to `true`, the problem disappears. And it makes no sense.

This is the effect I see if it's set to `false`

[image]

Comment: is it iPhone X and if not which device is it?

Comment: No, actually my iPhone 6S. Not even a simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given a lot of context here, but I was faced with a similar problem and found a solution.

It's actually not the toolbar becoming higher, but the view above it not extending all of the way down to the tab bar. Now I don't know if you are using Storyboards or doing this programatically. In the child view of the UITabBarController you need to set **Extend Edges -> Under Opaque Bars** in the Storyboard or the property **extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars** if you are doing it in code.

If you build this up with the storyboard, you can actually see the extra gap if you use an **Opaque Tab Bar** for your simulated metric on the Bottom Bar.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when setting `isTranslucent` to false.  My solution however was a bit of a workaround, which is to keep `isTranslucent` to true, but set the `UITabBar backgroundColor` to the colour I want it to be and it seems to negate the `isTranslucent` effect.